# Advising an emacs function; defadvice

Tags: emacs, defadvice, advising-functions

I'm trying to advise a function in emacs, but nothing happens.

```
(defadvice save-place-find-file-hook (after recenter activate)
  "Recenter after getting to saved place."
  (recenter))
```

Recentering doesn't happen, that is. If have a `(message "foo")` instead, foo is indeed displayed. What is it that I don't know about defadvice?

Comment: The function might be called from a location that saves (and later restores) the display layout, that way your call to `recenter` don't take effect.

Comment: Maybe instead try something like `(buffer-file-name)` to find out if the correct buffer is being recentered?

Comment: Also, perhaps try `(recenter-top-bottom)`, just in case?

Comment: The buffer is correct, and `(recenter-top-bottom)` does nothing as well...

Comment: Also tried a `(flash-line-highlight)` and that worked.

Comment: How am I calling `recenter` from `recenter`? Also, I don't seem to need to activate this advice (emacs 24.2), but doing so doesn't help either. I tried with `(message (buffer-file-name))` and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

`find-file-hook` is run before the buffer is displayed, so your recentering does not apply to the buffer you think it does and is undone immediately after it happened, when `find-file` replaces the current buffer with the new buffer in the selected window.

Comment: Sounds like you must be right. Still, the flash-line works, but perhaps that's due to some peculiarity of how this buffer is replaced under my feet... Well, what can you do..

Comment: The flash-line works because it causes actual display, whereas recenter only makes changes that are made visible at the next redisplay.  Try to add `(sit-for 1)` after your `(recenter)` to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Ok, yeah, my advice function is run before the buffer comes in view, the visibly flashed line just stays around long enough to be seen once it does. So perhaps I would have to advice find-find-* somehow, or even deeper...

Comment: I think the right way to do it is to use `find-file-hook` like you do, but in that hook you want to use something like `(run-with-timer 0 nil (lambda (buf) (dolist (win (get-buffer-window-list buf nil t)) (with-selected-window win (recenter)))) (current-buffer))`.